# Replacement for name locator strategy in Appium version >= 1.5.0

Tags: java, android, ios, appium

I am writing Mobile App automation test cases for Android/iOS using java and appium.

I have upgraded my appium version from 1.4.16 to 1.5.3. Now I am not able use name locator.

**name Locator:-**

```
By.name("name here")
```

Remove long-deprecated name locator strategy in Appium [v1.5](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.5.0)

I have tried findElementByAccessibilityId locator. But this doesn't help me.

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("name");
```

FYI I don't have specific id or class to use it. What is the replacement for name locator ?

Comment: In  appium 1.5 "name" locator got deprecated "Remove long-deprecated name locator strategy"
This link will help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bT3tqaLNn-Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using wildcards with xpath's can be very slow as it will scan the entire tree. It's also prone to returning the incorrect element if there are more than 1 item with the same name. Use precise locators wherever possible. Example: `By.xpath("//UIAButton[@name='foo']")`

Answer (score 1):

If accessibilityID isn't getting you there, have you tried using xpath with something like the below?

```
By.xpath("//*[@name='enter name here']")
```

Comment: I have tried xpath. Its works. I am referring "text" as name. What attributes are accessed by accessibilityID ?

Comment: I believe that it's different for iOS and Android:
iOS: it first looks for an accessibility ID that matches; if it doesn't find one, it'll look to the **label** attribute. From there, I've found that it looks to the good ole **name** attribute (though I know that many have been unsuccessful using it as a drop-in replacement for the name locator).
Android: it looks to the **android:id** attribute